# Can a 3rd party iPhone web browser (based on the SDK) access the contents of a page?

Tags: iphone

### Can a 3rd party iPhone web browser (based on the SDK) access the contents of a page?

For example, can I select a portion of a page I'm viewing in my custom-made 3rd party iPhone app-based web browser and then instruct the browser app to perform an operation with the selected text and/or html-embedded image?

Comment: I have no idea what this question means? You've written your own web browser? You want to choose some of that page and then get a different browser to do something with it? Why?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the content of a `UIWebView` directly. You can however use javascript to access the selected text in a `UIWebView`. There is even a [tutorial](http://zaldzbugz.wordpress.com/category/iphone/how-to-get-the-highlighted-text-in-uiwebview/) that explains how you would do just that.